# Jquery ajax call to google map api gives syntaxError: invalid label

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I'm performing a ajax call with jsonp to the google map api v3, but it always goes into the error function, and in the firefox console log I get the error

SyntaxError: invalid label
"results" : [

By clicking it I can see that I get all the right information in the browser, but for some reasons I receive this syntax Error message.

Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
        data: { latlng: latitude +","+longitude, sensor: "true" },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json.d);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Hit error fn!");
        }
    });
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    dataType: "jsonp",
```

with

```
    dataType: "json",
```

because you're doing a json request, not a jsonp one.

And you're not supposed to get something in `json.d`. You'd better alert (or console.log) `json` or `json.results`.

Note that you may not use Google's geocoding API from outside of a page including a map (your origin wouldn't be accepted).

Comment: Shouldn't I use JsonP since it is cross-domain?
Anyway, by using json I get 200 status ok, but the call fails with nothing in the response result

Comment: In JSONP, the server calls a method in your code (the answer is `someMethod(something);` instead of `"someJson"`). You can't call in JSONP a server made for JSON. And with the [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control), there is no more reason to use JSONP.

Comment: Any clue why I get the error even using json?
In firefox is red:
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=63.43048700000001%2C10.395061&sensor=true 200 OK 55ms

Response is empty

Comment: Are you calling from a page with a map ? Do you respect the terms of use ("the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited")?